# Is there any SafeArea Widget for Native Android development?

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to occupy as much space as available on notched android devices. In `Flutter` development, there is widget called `SafeArea` which automatically adjusts your view depending on whether the device has a notch or not. Even in `iOS` development whenever we add `constraints` using `storyboard`, we can add it according to `SafeArea`.
But I couldn't find anything similar to it in Native Android development.

In my `styles.xml` for v28 I have added something as follows

```
 <style name="TPAFTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"> 
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item> 
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item> 
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item> 
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item> 
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    </style>
```

But is it possible to detect whether device has Notch or not in layout file itself and adjust the layout according.
I am using `Constraintlayout` in my App. As my app has image at the top it gets cropped if the device has notch at the top.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the answer. Just use `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your ConstraintLayout or any other top level Layout which you're using

Answer (score 0):

I think the right option is to use CoordinatorLayout as a parent for your ConstraintLayout. CoordinatorLayout does lots of things and handling the system area is one of them (which I'd say isn't obvious...). It internally sets OnApplyWindowInsetsListener which is called by the system with information about sizes of system elements. CoordinatorLayout handles this calls and sets the right padding for its children. So, in Android it's more complicated than in iOS, you'll have to get used to it...

I'd recommend this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mGDMVRO3iE